# Matplotlib Button draw line

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I want to create something that can show (and hide with the same button) a line.

Here's what I have for the moment :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

class Index(object):
   ind = 0

   def test(self, event):
     self.plt.plot([0, 0], [1, 1])
     plt.draw()


callback = Index()
axtest = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
btest = Button(axtest, 'Test')
btest.on_clicked(callback.test)


plt.show()
```

Can someone help me with this script ? I really can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: I run your code and got an empty plot with a test button. I'm not sure what you get or what you want to achieve. Could you post an image of what you want or a better description? Sorry if it's evident. But see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.plt` does not make sense. Apart, your scipt will always add a new plot. Instead you would maybe want to toggle the visibility (and possibly change the data) of an existing plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

class Index(object):
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line

    def test(self, event):
        if self.line.get_visible():
            self.line.set_visible(False)
        else:
            # possibly change data here, for now same data is used
            self.line.set_data([0,1],[0,1])
            self.line.set_visible(True)
            self.line.axes.relim()
            self.line.axes.autoscale_view()
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()

line, = plt.plot([],[], visible=False)

callback = Index(line)
axtest = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
btest = Button(axtest, 'Test')
btest.on_clicked(callback.test)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Can this be done over an image that has been displayed using `plt.imshow(img)`?